# Authenticate with Cognito Federated Identities

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to use Amazon Cognito in my web app (Java based). I want to have some kind of authentication hub (Amazon Cognito) to authenticate user with multiple Auth Providers - that's why I want to use Amazon Cognito! :)

Firstly, I set up User Pool (I have my UserPoolId: eu-central-1_xxxxxxxxxx) and created there one user. Next I created Identity Pool with IdentityPoolId (eu-central-1:yyyyyyyyyy). Then I authenticate with AWS JavaScript SDK to UserPool to get idToken and it working quite fine! I receive idToken from Cognito UserPool. Then I am sending this idToken to my backend app (Java based) and there I want to validate this idToken with IdentityPool. I added new Authentication Provider - Cognito with UserPoolId and newly created id of an App that I added in UserPool. I tried to follow with this tutorial:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-amazon-cognito-in-your-website-for-simple-aws-authentication/ 
But everytime I make

```
GetID
```

request I recevied Exception with

```
com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool.
```

My Java code is below:

```
final AmazonCognitoIdentityClient identityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(
                new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey"));
identityClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));

GetIdRequest idRequest = new GetIdRequest();
idRequest.setAccountId("accountId");
idRequest.setIdentityPoolId(identityPoolId);

final String providerName = "cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_xxxxxxxx";

Map providerTokens = new HashMap();
providerTokens.put(providerName, idToken);
idRequest.setLogins(providerTokens);

GetIdResult idResp = identityClient.getId(idRequest);
```

Does anyone could help me with this task? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Kamil :)

Answer (score 1):

There are three pieces of data that need to match in this scenario:

- Provider as configured in AWS.
- Provider as put into the `Logins` map.
- `iss` value (issuer) in the id token.

When I have seen this error, it has been because the value in the Logins map does not match the provider as configured in AWS.

For example, an unexpected port number or [trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451605/token-is-not-from-a-supported-provider-of-this-identity-pool-amazon-mobile-hub-a) can cause these not to match.

Beyond this, there are a couple of settings in AWS that need to line up.

**Provider as configured in AWS**

With a Cognito User Pool, Amazon configures this name for you, so it's non-configurable on the backend.  The format of the `providerName` in your Java code looks good, but first I'd triple check the `xxxxxxx` part for a typo.

**App Client settings**

Then, make sure your App Client has Cognito enabled in your User Pool settings:

[image: Cognito enabled for App Client]

**Federated Identities settings**

Next, in your federated identities settings, verify that the user pool id and client id appear in the Cognito tab under "Authentication providers", and that they match your user pool and App Client.

[image: Federated Identities settings]

**JWT issuer**

Finally, I would expect the error to be `"Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName"` if there was a problem with the `iss` value in the JWT.  However, decoding the id token you get back and inspecting the contents (as suggested in another answer) is also good advice.

If all these pieces appear to be in place, and the error persists, please leave a comment.  Happy Hacking!

Answer (score 0):

When you created your user pool double check you have all the expected federated providers supported.  If you use developer authenticated make sure you add that 'login....' domain as well.
Grab your/a token and look at it in jwt.io for clues as well.